# SVG style rules aren't respected when added through CSS, but respected when explicitly set through element <style> tag in HTML

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to integrate a small SVG image on my web-page. I'm using it as `background-image` for my `body`. The image is a small path grid, painted black. **Please note the `<style>` tag.**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1000px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 1000 500" zoomAndPan="disable" preserveAspectRatio="none">

    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
        line
        {
            stroke: rgba(0,0,0, 0.75); /* Color */
            stroke-width: 1px;
        }
    ]]></style>

    <line x1="1100" y1="500" x2="-1000" y2="250"/>
    <line x1="1100" y1="500" x2="-1000" y2="-100"/>
    <line x1="1100" y1="500" x2="-1000" y2="-500"/>
    <line x1="1100" y1="500" x2="-250" y2="-500"/>
    <line x1="1100" y1="500" x2="300" y2="-500"/>
    <line x1="1100" y1="500" x2="750" y2="-500"/>

    <line x1="1750" y1="0" x2="750" y2="500"/>
    <line x1="1500" y1="0" x2="500" y2="500"/>
    <line x1="1150" y1="0" x2="150" y2="500"/>
    <line x1="700" y1="0" x2="-300" y2="500"/>
    <line x1="150" y1="0" x2="-850" y2="500"/>

</svg>
```

The thing is, if I set it as a `background image` in my CSS, like so:

```
.body{
    background-image: url("images/intro.svg");
}
```

It shows up **white**.
Alternatively, when I set it explicitly, through HTML:

```
<body style="background-image: url('images/intro.svg');">foo foo foo</body>
```

it shows up fine. Black, with 75% opacity (alpha).

What is going on here? Anyway I can fix this, without having to do it explicitly through HTML?

Comment: Are you sure "it shows up in white" and not "it doesn't show up at all because you missed the `v` off the end of the URL"?

Comment: Yeah, this was just a typo as I was making the minimal working example. Don't worry about it, and thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: is the path right? (note that css paths are relative to the css file and not the document.)

Comment: @RolandStarke make it into an answer, so I can accept it. This was it. ugh.